# GitLens-like issue linking in vim

Tags: git

In VSCode, GitLens allows you to hover over a line and get a link to the PR containing the most recent change for that line. Basically with a single click you can open up the PR which often contains valuable information that you wouldn't get by just checking the diff using the commit SHA.

[image]

Is there a way to get a similar issue linking set up in vim? I've looked at git plugins like fugitive or coc-git and while those support git blame in some form, neither of them seem to offer a feature to easily open up issues on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

You might want fugitive's `:Git blame` combined with [tpope/vim-rhubarb](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rhubarb). Doing so will let `:GBrowse` work with GitHub-based remotes, so that you can quickly open those PRs.

Another option might be something like the `gh pr view` command (which has from  `--web` to open a browser) from https://github.com/cli/cli or the equivalent from [hub](https://github.com/github/hub). You could certainly build mappings, *e.g.*,

```
nnoremap <localleader>pr :execute '!gh pr view --web' <cword><CR><CR>
```